# Saving Multiple JQuery Sortable in same table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have multiple Ul in which I can drag and drop li elements between them:

```
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="header text-center">
        <h4 class="title">Curriculum</h4>
        <p class="category">Start putting together your course by creating sections, lectures and practice quizzes below.</p>   
        </div>       
        <div class="inner-box">
            <div class="header">
            <h4 class="title text-left">Section 1:</h4> 
            <div class=" header text-left">     
            <ul class="sortable ui-sortable" style="list-style-type: none;">


            <li class="lecture ui-sortable-handle">
            <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #17AA1C;"></span> Lecture 3: Testing</small></p>
            </li><li class="lecture ui-sortable-handle">
            <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #17AA1C;"></span> Lecture 1: Testing</small></p>
            </li><li class="lecture ui-sortable-handle">
            <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #17AA1C;"></span> Lecture 2: Testing</small></p>
            </li>  


            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="inner-box">
            <div class="header">
            <h4 class="title text-left">Section 2:</h4> 
            <div class=" header text-left">     
            <ul class="sortable ui-sortable" style="list-style-type: none;">

            <li class="lecture ui-sortable-handle">
            <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #17AA1C;"></span> Lecture 5: fasd</small></p>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="inner-box">
        <div class="header">
        <h4 class="title text-left">Section 3:</h4> 
        <div class=" header text-left">     
    <ul class="sortable ui-sortable" style="list-style-type: none;">

    <li class="lecture ui-sortable-handle">
    <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #17AA1C;"></span> Lecture 4: asdf</small></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And Script that is letting it drag and drop between multiple  Ul is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.sortable').sortable({
            connectWith: '.sortable',
            revert: true
        });
    </script>
```

The Output is Something Like:
[image]

Basically I am trying to save in the database the section number and the lecture number that it has.

For Example :

```
section_id | lecture_id | 

1              3                
1              1              
1              2              
2              5              
3              4
```

So that When I load it loads in the order it saves.

I am not able to apply ajax to save with this kind of structure.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not working or what have you tried? Sortable has a few methods to collect this detail: `serialize` and `toArray` and that can be passed to your scripts via AJAX to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/wqxpu2cz/) here. Have a look.

**Please note: I have give `id`s to the `<ul>`s and `<li>`s**

Here is the code:

**JS:**

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sortable',
  revert: true
});

$('#btn').click(function() {
    var arr = [];
    $.each( $("ul.sortable"), function( index, value ) {
    var sortedIDs = $( this ).sortable( "toArray" );
    var sectionId = $(this).attr('id');
    arr[index] = [];
    arr[index]['sectionId'] = sectionId;
    arr[index]['sortedIDs'] = sortedIDs;
    //console.log(sortedIDs);
  })
    console.log(arr);
  alert(arr.serializeArray())
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer-box">
    <div class="header text-center">
        <h4 class="title">Curriculum</h4>
        <p class="category">Start putting together your course by creating sections, lectures and practice quizzes below.</p>   
        </div>       
        <div class="inner-box">
            <div class="header">
            <h4 class="title text-left">Section 1:</h4> 
            <div class=" header text-left">     
            <ul class="sortable ui-sortable" style="list-style-type: none;" id="sec1">


            <li class="lecture ui-sortable-handle" id="lec3">
            <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #17AA1C;"></span> Lecture 3: Testing</small></p>
            </li>

            <li class="lecture ui-sortable-handle" id="lec1">
            <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #17AA1C;"></span> Lecture 1: Testing</small></p>
            </li>

            <li class="lecture ui-sortable-handle" id="lec2">
            <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #17AA1C;"></span> Lecture 2: Testing</small></p>
            </li>  


            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="inner-box">
            <div class="header">
            <h4 class="title text-left">Section 2:</h4> 
            <div class=" header text-left">     
            <ul class="sortable ui-sortable" style="list-style-type: none;" id="sec2">

            <li class="lecture ui-sortable-handle" id="lec5">
            <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #17AA1C;"></span> Lecture 5: fasd</small></p>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="inner-box">
        <div class="header">
        <h4 class="title text-left">Section 3:</h4> 
        <div class=" header text-left">     
    <ul class="sortable ui-sortable" style="list-style-type: none;" id="sec3">

    <li class="lecture ui-sortable-handle" id="lec4">
    <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #17AA1C;"></span> Lecture 4: asdf</small></p>
    </li>
</ul>

<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Get IDs" id="btn"/>
```